# How to Build the WP7 app in Release mode?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I have develop a application in Windows phone7,it is working while i build the application in Debug mode.But ,when i try to  build the application in release mode then controls are not find for example i am using

```
      internal Microsoft.Phone.Controls.DatePicker DateToDialIn;

      internal Microsoft.Phone.Controls.TimePicker TimeToDialIn;

      internal Microsoft.Phone.Controls.ListPicker lstPickerLocation;
```

These controls are not find please help me why these controls are not find ... in Release mode

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to include your references in your folder and have the 'copy local' set to true.

Comment: Hi.. i have include references in my Project solution.where i can set the copy local set true.I don't Know how to set please help me.

Comment: You can set the copy local at the bottom right 'properties' screen in you projects reference page.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on Reference -> Choose Properties -> Set Copy Local to True